# HTTP upload server in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, multipart, http-upload

I'm thinking to build an HTTP upload server in Ruby for my project. So far, I'm looking at setting up a Rack server to run with "Rainbow!" or a sinatra server with Rack middleware. The server is required to support HTTP uploads with multipart and chunking. Is this a good choice?

I'd love to see some examples how to set up a simple HTTP upload server but I couldn't find anywhere on the 'net.

Comment: Would need more information on your requirements to comment further. Here's an example of handling files in Sinatra: http://alfuken.tumblr.com/post/874428235/upload-and-download-files-in-sinatra

Answer (score 1):

Since a file upload can take a while, an important point of uploading files in Ruby are blocking processes while a file is uploaded. You might want to look into projects that are based on EventMachine and/or Goliath to achieve non-blocking processing of HTTP requests. Some ideas here:

- http://isurfsoftware.com/blog/2011/05/12/2011-experimenting-with-goliath-and-EventMachine/
- https://gist.github.com/rweald/969981
- http://www.bigfastblog.com/rubys-eventmachine-part-3-thin